# Facebook Login with Read and Publish(Write) permissions

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying Facebook Login in Android with `LoginManager` class. I want read and write permissions during login only. The issue I am facing is , If I try with

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginWithReadPermissions();
LoginManager.getInstance().loginWithPublishPermissions();
```

If Facebook App is not installed, Facebook WebView loads up, I enter credentials, I see two permissions screen (One for Read and One for write) and then again Login Screen.Which basically, creates bad user experience.

It happens because, both loginWithxxxPermissions() methods,starts a new login flow.But actually, It should not show Login Screen for already logged in user.

I am not able to find any method to pass the accessToken to let me the method know that, the new permission query is for already logged in user.

Anyone, Please help me out or suggest some other alternative, But the requirement is clear. I need Read/Write permissions without showing Login screen twice.

Comment: Hello Brijeshn, do you really need to ask both permissions at the same time ? If you can't solve that like that, it might be a way to ease the process at least.

Comment: Yes, Since there is no UI should be shown, Yes We can do that by handling in onResume(). Once we get the read permission, use a flag to set the read request status and then check the flag in onResume() for gettting write permission